geom_tile unable to sort - diagonal
I've certain chromosomal locations called bands. I'm interested to generate combinations of them and then using ggplot's geom_tile plot them. Ideally, they should appear as a diagonal (upper or lower).
However, I'm unable to achieve it. I've tried different approaches but in vain.
chrom_locations <- c("10q23.31", "12p13.33", "12q24.33", "14q32.33", "17q21.33", "19p13.11", "19q13.31", "19q13.42", "19q13.43", "20q13.33", "22q11.22", "22q13.33")


combinations_list <- combn(( chrom_locations), 2, simplify = FALSE)

len_combinations_list<-length(combinations_list) ## 120
df_pairs_pvalue <- data.frame(
  band1 = character(len_combinations_list),      # Numeric column
  band2 = character(len_combinations_list),  # Character column
  count_both = numeric(len_combinations_list)

)


df_pairs_pvalue <- data.frame(
  band1 = character(len_combinations_list),      # Numeric column
  band2 = character(len_combinations_list),  # Character column
  count_both = numeric(len_combinations_list)

)
for(x in seq(1,len_combinations_list  )){
  
  ##store in df_paris data frame
  band1<-combinations_list[[x]][1]
  band2<-combinations_list[[x]][2]
  
  df_pairs_pvalue[x,"band1"]<-  band1
  df_pairs_pvalue[x,"band2"]<-  band2
  df_pairs_pvalue[x,"count_both"]<- c(sample(1:100, 1, replace = T)) 
   
}
library(stringr)

sorted_locations <- stringr::str_sort(chrom_locations, numeric = TRUE)

# Reorder the levels of band1 and band2
df_pairs_pvalue$band1 <- factor(df_pairs_pvalue$band1, levels = sorted_locations)
df_pairs_pvalue$band2 <- factor(df_pairs_pvalue$band2, levels = sorted_locations)

ggplot(df_pairs_pvalue, aes(band2, band1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = count_both ), color = "black") +
  #scale_fill_viridis()+ 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#075AFF",
                       mid = "#FFFFCC",
                       high = "#FF0000",
                       midpoint = 0,        # This sets the middle point of the scale in data terms
                       limits = c(0, 130),   # Replace -3 and 3 with your actual data range min and max
                       breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), # Customize breaks if needed, or adjust according to your data range
                       labels = seq(0, 100, 10)) 
  

I get attached plot. 
I've tried other way to sort as:
desired_order <-gtools::mixedsort( rownames( df_focal_cna_filtered_xposed))

df_pairs_pvalue_adj$band1 <- factor(df_pairs_pvalue_adj$band1, levels = desired_order)
df_pairs_pvalue_adj$band2 <- factor(df_pairs_pvalue_adj$band2, levels = desired_order)

This also doesn't work.
Any help would be highly appreciated

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Sorry, I thought I had put the code. I missed it. I have updated the code now.

Your second line of code throws an error because chrom_locations (as you've shared it) is a vector, not a data frame, so it doesn't have rownames. If I delete the rownames() call to get past that, then the definition of df_pairs_value throws an error because len_combinations_list is not defined. So I define len_combinations_list = length(combinations_list) to get past that, but there's another error a few lines later because df_pairs_pvalue_adj is not defined. Please do better at making your example reproducible.

Conceptually, to make an upper triangular matrix, you need to configure your data so that the y values included are always >= the x values.  I don't see anywhere you've attempted to do that. pmin and pmax may help with that. Maybe this hint is enough for you to solve the problem. If not please edit your question to make it reproducible!

@GregorThomas Sorry about the mistakes in the code. I have edited the code to make reproducible. I am unable to understadn pmin and pmax

## make your factors `ordered` so comparisons like `<` and `>` work
df_pairs_pvalue$band1 <- factor(df_pairs_pvalue$band1, levels = sorted_locations, ordered = TRUE)
df_pairs_pvalue$band2 <- factor(df_pairs_pvalue$band2, levels = sorted_locations, ordered = TRUE)

## use pmin and pmax to get the row-wise min and max factor values
df_pairs_pvalue$minband = with(df_pairs_pvalue, pmin(band1, band2))
df_pairs_pvalue$maxband = with(df_pairs_pvalue, pmax(band1, band2))

## use those row-wise min and max values as the x and y aesthetics

ggplot(df_pairs_pvalue, aes(minband, maxband)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = count_both ), color = "black") +
  #scale_fill_viridis()+ 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#075AFF",
                       mid = "#FFFFCC",
                       high = "#FF0000",
                       midpoint = 0,        # This sets the middle point of the scale in data terms
                       limits = c(0, 130),   # Replace -3 and 3 with your actual data range min and max
                       breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), # Customize breaks if needed, or adjust according to your data range
                       labels = seq(0, 100, 10)) 


